# SQL-запрос о количестве записей со схожим содержимым

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица, в первой колонке которой прописаны номера тендеров, во второй прописаны ИНН компаний, которые в данном тендере принимали участие. В тендере может участвовать неограниченное число  компаний. Задача: найти количество тендеров со схожим набором компаний.

Пример исходной таблицы:
[image: Пример исходной таблицы:]

Результат (по два одинаковых тендера под номером 6 и 11, 2 и 9):
[image: Результат (по два одинаковых тендера под номером 6 и 11, 2 и 9):]

Были мысли сделать сортировку по инн внутри группировки по номеру тендера, а потом записать по порядку все инн в одну строку по каждому тендеру, но с реализацией у меня проблемы, может кто-нибудь может помочь?

Answer (score 0):

У Вас изначально структура таблицы не правильная. Вам необходимо разнести информацию о тендерах и их участниках в разные таблицы, таким образом Вы сможете искать среди участников тендеры по ID этого самого тендера.

Например так:

```
select * from `companyes` where `tender_id` = 10;
```

Или так:

```
select * from `tenders` where `inn` in (select `inn` from `companyes` where `status` = 'active');
```